# C++ pointer to 2D array

Tags: c++, pointers, multidimensional-array

Hi I know there are a lot of similar questions but I've been through them and I can't seem to make my function work. I need to return a pointer to a 2D array. So far I am using this code:

(This code is a function in Level.cpp)

```
TileType* CLevel::getTiles()
{
TileType (*matrix_ptr)[31] = tiles;

return *matrix_ptr;
 }
```

(TileType is an enum) This function is just returning one row and I obviously need both. Any suggestions?

Header file Level.h:

```
class CLevel 
{
private:

list<CBox> boxes;
TileType tiles[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];
CPlayer player;

public:
CLevel();
~CLevel();

CPlayer* getPlayer();
list<CBox>* getBoxes();
TileType** getTiles();
};
```

Comment: tiles is defined like so: TileType tiles[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];

Comment: tiles is defined in the header file. I'll edit my question to show the header file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you should do is either this:

```
// Class declaration
class CLevel
{
public:
   TileType (*getTiles())[GRID_WIDTH];

   TileType tiles[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];

   //...
};

// Implementation
TileType (*CLevel::getTiles())[GRID_WIDTH]
{
   return tiles;
}
```

or this:

```
// Class declaration
class CLevel
{
public:
   TileType (&getTiles())[GRID_WIDTH][GRID_HEIGHT];

   TileType tiles[GRID_HEIGHT][GRID_WIDTH];

   //...
};

// Implementation
TileType (&CLevel::getTiles())[GRID_WIDTH][GRID_HEIGHT]
{
   return tiles;
}
```

It's a bit of a complicated declaration but read it inside out: in both cases `getTiles()` is a function that returns a reference to a 2D array of tiles (the example shows two forms of syntax). By calling `getTiles()` you're actually referring to `tiles`. You can even call the function it in this way: `getTiles()[i][j]`.

Comment: It works, but I don't see many places where such a construct would be useful.

Comment: I have used the function you wrote here and I am getting an error that 'tiles' is undefined. I cannot understand how I am getting this error :/ I am also getting an error that 'function returning array is not allowed'.

Also I need to access the elements of the array ultimately so I need to call the function as you wrote: getTiles()[i][j]. 

(I am using this function to store tiles in an array for a Sokoban game)

Comment: Well it compiles for me on gcc-4.3.4, see [this](http://ideone.com/TkCqJ). What compiler are you using?

Comment: I am using Visual C++ 2010 Express. 

You are not making the function part of a class though. My function looks like this:

TileType CLevel::(*getTiles())[GRID_WIDTH]
{
   return tiles;
}

Comment: The return type of the function is TileType which is just an enum though. How are we returning an array then?

This is what I have: enum TileType { GROUND, WALL, GOAL };

With this code: TileType CLevel::(*getTiles())[GRID_WIDTH]
I am getting an error 'Expected an identifier Explicit type is missing, int assumed'

Comment: Your comments suggests that you're declaring `CLevel::getTiles()` wrong. I've modified the answer so that `getTiles` is declared as a member function of `CLevel` like you wanted. Notice carefully where I've put `CLevel::`.

Comment: The header file is giving me the error 'function returning array is not allowed' I am declaring it like this: TileType getTiles()[GRID_WIDTH]; in the header file. Then in the cpp file I am getting an error that it is incompatible with the declaration type. How do you correctly declare it in the header file?

Comment: The declaration in the header file and the source file should always be consistent. Are you implementing the function in the source file like it is declared in `CLevel`? Look at my answer.

Comment: Ok no errors so far. Time to test it out. Thanks for all your help! Hope it works well. One other thing: Is the explanation you wrote under your reply still valid with the new implementation?

Comment: Of course, it is still valid. I've just modified the answer to show you two ways of declaring `getTiles`. If you find this answer helpful, please upvote it and then accept it according to [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Comment: Thank you for all your help! It is now working. The only issue I have now is how to do clear screen and gotoxy for the game since there doesn't seem to be an inbuilt function.

Answer (score 2):

Don't define getTiles().

You are completely breaking the encapsulation of the class. This doesn't always matter but in this case the C/C++ 2D array is not a fit structure for passing outside where its dimensions might not be known.

So define your operations on tiles as methods of CLevel.

Comment: However flawed the design might be, this is irrelevant to the question asked

Answer (score -1):

If you want to return a pointer to a 2d array, then your function declaration should be:

```
TileType** CLevel::getTiles()
```

And your return should be matrix_ptr, not its pointer content (which is a one-dimension array).

```
return matrix_ptr;
```

Comment: When I do this I get an error: Return value type does not match the function type

Comment: So, how is your matrix_ptr declaration?

Comment: @RicardPérezdelCampo `matrix_ptr` is defined within `getTiles`.

Comment: Like I wrote above: TileType (*matrix_ptr)[31] = tiles;

Comment: I mean the line that declares the matrix_ptr var. But it seems that it is something like TileType ***matrix_ptr isn't it? I didn't read your comment on your main question where you specify that tiles is already a 2d array.

Comment: TileType **matrix_ptr would give you a pointer to an array of pointers which is not how you have declared tiles. I don't think tiles is safe to let escape the class.

Comment: A 2D array cannot be converted to a `**`.